# Windows detects no mouse clicks inside a small area of the screen

Tags: windows-10, mouse

A strange problem has developed on my Windows 10 machine. When I'm in Windows, if I click inside a certain area in the centre of the screen, the mouse click does not register, and if the cursor should change based on the content I'm hovering over, it doesn't.

Here is a demonstration of what I mean. In this GIF, I move my mouse into the area and attempt to select some text, but nothing happens. When I then move my mouse out of the area, the cursor changes to the correct "text selector" cursor and I can select the text fine.

[image: Demo]

The mouse wheel and clicks (left, right and middle) don't work while the mouse is in this area. There is a short delay after Windows startup before this problem begins, and it also doesn't occur on the Windows lock screen. I have two displays, but only my primary display is affected. How can I get my cursor to work properly again?

Comment: If you disconnect primary display does it occur in the other one? (if you swap displays does it occur on the same monitor, or still on the primary display?) When this started to happen? Did you changed anything on the pc around that time?

Comment: Maybe it is something like [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/invisible-window-on-my-desk-top/ce428218-e749-401e-ab1d-28bc1ca814aa) or [that](http://superuser.com/q/991163/432690).

Comment: @MátéJuhász It started today, and I haven't changed anything. I'll test with disconnecting displays as soon as I can and then update my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem must've been caused by some sort of adware program, because I ran ADWCleaner and the problem was instantly resolved without the need for even a restart.

Comment: Set this as solution, to mark the question to be solved.

Comment: @davidbaumann I need to wait 2 days before I can do that, because it's my own answer.

Comment: Reboot helped me too. Mine started after a reboot after a video driver install.

Comment: Ran ADWCleaner and the problem disappeared.

Comment: It was Discord for me. I went into Task Manager, force closed Discord, and voila, fixed.

Answer (score 22):

If you minimize everything (so as to not accidentally close the wrong application) then click into the empty space and press alt + f4 it will close that invisible application that's running.

Comment: It worked for me. I was really wondering what could have caused it. How to detect that application?

Comment: This version was *MY* issue. Invisible window "on top".  No malware, just SLACK.  Minimized, then moved mouse across screen until right click gave "wrong" menu or back for "right" menu.  
To find app, I ran Windows Spy from AutoHotKey and again moved the mouse over desktop until Spy showed the name of the app (Slack).
Stopped all Slack processes and problem disappeared. 
Generally I can run Slack with no issue.

Comment: @HerbM It was slack for me too. Simply quit that from system tray. Everything works fine again.

Comment: I had the same issue with Slack as you...

Comment: The same here, Slack was the problem. Killing slack.exe from task manager solved the problem.

Comment: I had this problem in a band down the right hand side of my secondary monitor - also turned out to be an invisible Slack window.  Used the process selector in Fiddler to hover over the area, and it told me the app involved.  Fixed by killing all Slack processes.  Doesn't seem to recur when I restart Slack - we'll see after the next reboot.

Comment: Slack here too.

Comment: Slack here as well, however the alt-f4 trick did not work, I used the command prompt command, `taskkill /im slack.exe /f` and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Simply closing and opening Slack using the taskbar icon worked for me, no need to kill anything.

Comment: @HerbM "No malware, just SLACK." With the memory hogging, random bouts of ~100% CPU usage forcing a restart, and this invisible window issue, I think it's safe to start calling it malware.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case it was a malfunctioning of the AVIRA virus scanner and the area was in the top left corner of my screen. It obviously tried to open an ad window but the script got stuck.

I installed another virus scanner, uninstalled AVIRA and now everything is fine again.

It took me around 4 hours to figure out what was actually going on.

Answer (score 0):

Did you just upgrade to windows 10? Try installing the latest version of logitech setpoint 
http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/setpoint

Comment: Thanks for answering, but no, I've been on Windows 10 for a while now, from a clean install.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR kill `explorer.exe` and launch it back.

---

I had an invisible transparent window that was blocking ~3rd of my screen, that portion of the screen was not registering any clicks or mouse moves. (I *think* it was left behind by my Dell monitor tool that allows "snapping" a window to a portion of the screen, but that's not important).

To get rid of the invisible window launch the Task Manager via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>, kill the `explorer.exe` process, and then launch it back again (also via "task manager - file - run new task").

Answer (score -1):

I know this thread is old but thought that I'd add that I was having this problem and after reading this thread I went into my settings and turned off the pop up blocker and the problem was instantly fixed