# How to eliminate Chromium virus?

Tags: virus

I've been seeing the window shown in screenshot below from time to time across multiple Windows 10 installations. Recently it has become impossible to kill: no tab in taskbar, no process visible, I just have to reboot.

Virus scan doesn't find anything. Help :(

[image]

Comment: Please get [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), identify what executable owns this window, and update your question with details. See https://superuser.com/a/249416/707676 for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, download and then run [Process Explorer](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip).

When running (run it with Administrator's rights), hold your mouse left button on the *target icon* (see the red arrow on the screenshot below).

[image: Procexp screenshot]

Then drag this icon on the window you are looking for.

Now Process Explorer will highlight the process owning this Window (you should be able to kill it by hitting *Del* Key.

Comment: Works, thanks! Too bad it's not possible from that software to remove the bug. I can't even see the path to the .exe, it says "[access denied]" in the path field

Comment: If it says [acess denied], it mean you havn't run procexp as administrator. Try to run it with `/e` parameter `procexp.exe /e` then you should have more informations

Comment: I'll try next time (this damn thing comes when it wants), thanks a lot!